# "Accomplice of" or "accomplice with"

Tags: prepositions

I have this sentence:

> This man was an **accomplice with** the thief.

It sounds very unnatural to me as, correct me if I am wrong, "accomplice" conveys that the man was *with* the criminal i.e helping the criminal, so use of "with" in the sentence makes it superfluous.

http://www.yourdictionary.com/accomplice states that both "with" and "of" can be used. Please specify where to use which one.

Comment: "However,the source from where I took the sentence asks for strictly using "with". Hardly believable, with the Ngram Viewer results. You can provide the link to that source, can't you?

Comment: Well, I took the sentence from a local grammar practice workbook. I've already found many typos in it. Guess it's not reliable at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with you.

To me, `Frank was an accomplice of the thief.` sounds more natural than `accomplice with`.

[Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=accomplice%20of%2Caccomplice%20with&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Caccomplice%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caccomplice%20with%3B%2Cc0) comparing the two:

[image: Google Ngram]